# Will Neo4J be able to handle 40Giga of data?

Tags: neo4j

I have several data sheets in the total size of 40G and would like to represent it in a graph (there could be several nodes per row, and nodes will contain most of the data in the row either in labels or properties).

Could Neo4J handle this? What is the largest DB size (quantity of nodes, size on disk, etc. ) tested so far?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there are several installations with over 1B-2B relationships - capacity-wise, http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/capabilities-capacity.html is listing the current maximum.

Answer (score 6):

"40G of data" can vary quite a lot depending on how it's modeled in the graph. Have you got 40G of source data and would like to put it into neo4j, or have you calculated that your data will take roughly 40G of space in neo4j?

Depending on how you model your data you are able to remove some/a lot of duplicated data, i.e. instead of having some properties on all entities instead infer them from the surroundings via relationships.

Answer (score 5):

In Neo4j, data size is mainly limited by the address space of the primary keys for Nodes, Relationships, Properties and RelationshipTypes. Currently, the address space is as follows:

```
2ˆ35 (~ 34 billion) nodes
2ˆ35 (~ 34 billion) relationships
2ˆ36 (~ 68 billion) properties
2ˆ15 (~ 32 000) relationship types
```

Comment: As of neo4j 3, this is no longer true. For more information see http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity.